# Browser waits longer than expected

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I have some code, in which I'm trying to scrape a website. After a while, I think I'm being slowed down by the site. I can't chekc that, but this is happening within my code

```
z=timeit.default_timer()

try:
    WebDriverWait(browser,5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'''
        .//div[@collectionitem="title"]/descendant::div[@class="titleWidgetLayout"]/
        descendant::h1[@class="title"]''')))
except:
    print('Web Scraper not loaded')
    return 'Error Load'
n=timeit.default_timer()

print('Time actually waited',n-z)
```

I find that while at the beginning this time was about 1-2 seconds, it ends up turning into a 25 seconds wait. This not only slows down the code more than what is acceptable, how can the time waited be far longer than the 5 seconds I set up as timeout error trigger?

I guess this might be a blockage from the page, but in any case, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely occurring because the `webdriver` is set to wait until the page is ***completely*** (until the load symbol of the page is gone) done loading before looking for any *elements*.

So, if you page takes 23 seconds to load, and then your element is located after 3 seconds after page load, you would not throw a timeout from your `WebDriverWait` condition.

You can try to set the **Page Load Timeout** with this:

```
browser.set_page_load_timeout(5)
```

This way, if the page is taking too long to load, you can skip it? Other than that, you will have to wait until the page load is complete.

Comment: I have tried a different approach. After the first time it took longer than 10 seconds, I ordered the code to `time.sleep(3)` and afterwards just do a broser.find_element. Surprisingly, the code accepted it and just took 3.08 seconds to complete that part.